# How to truncate long string on firefox responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make the text display 2 line image below.
[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onxI6.png)

It is how's it look like on chrome, but in firefox it don't work. I found this website have tutorial in chrome. Link: https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/ . It is use -webkit-line-clamp to check at which line we want to add "...". However , on firefox, we don't have tag "-webkit-line-clamp" like this tutorial. So there are have any way to make text truncated on firefox. I had used javascript like below to trim string.

```
String.prototype.truncString = function(max, add){
    add = add || '...';
    return (this.length > max ? this.substring(0,max)+add : this);
};
if($(".smaller_768 ").width() < 200 && $(".smaller_768 ") > 120){
    trim_content(28);
}
function trim_content(numberofwords){
            $(".smaller_768").each(function(){
                var content = $.trim($(this).text());
                $(this).text(content.truncString(numberofwords, "..."));
            });
}
```

But It doesn't work well we when I change the device because the size of div is changed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The site you are referring to has more than one way to achieve this; among them two JS solutions (in the codepen) that seem to handle resizing of the area in which the text gets disabled, quite well …

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your function on window resize, using something like this:

```
$(window).on("resize", function(){
   if($(".smaller_768 ").width() < 200 && $(".smaller_768 ") > 120){
      trim_content(28);
   }
});
```

Using `resize` function, it will change the number of string each time you resize your browser